# How best to handle a POST with variable arguments?

Tags: php, mysql, web-services

I'm using php to parse an incoming POST (restful) query for an update to a database.  However, the user may choose to update any combination of ~10 fields at a time.  I know that i can handle this by doing isset like crazy on each potential item in $_POST[], but I'm wondering if there is a more standard way to do this (being that I'm no expert in php). 
Thanks!

Comment: foreach() loop check if field has a value.

Comment: would doing a switch statement work for you? plus maybe a wrapping it in a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only two way.

Iterate over fields and check existence in POST, or iterate over POST variables and check existance in fields set.

Answer (score 0):

$fields = array(

     'field1' => isset($_POST['one']) ? $_POST['one'] : null,

     'field2' => isset($_POST['two']) ? $_POST['two'] : null

);

for me, this is the best solution